# Question closed before I updated it. Do I need to just write a new one or just wait?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I recently asked this question: [How to go about finding where traffic is getting held up?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65449/how-to-go-about-finding-where-traffic-is-getting-held-up)

I just now updated the question, and honestly I don't know if it's an acceptable question even now, but it's one of those things where I simply don't have anywhere else to go for help so I hope that with my update it will be acceptable "enough". Although that's not why I'm writing this...

I received feedback that I needed to update the question, but it was closed before I was able to update it (I was still trying some other things and wanted to wait until I could update with results of all my own troubleshooting). Now that I've updated, will it possibly be reopened or should I just create a new question?

Comment: If your edit makes the question adhere to the site's /help/on-topic guidelines, then you're probably ok and that edit (only the first edit after it's put on hold... make it worthwhile!) took the question to the *reopen* review queue, and users are voting whether to reopen or leave it closed. That said, *this* question should probably have been posted on that site's meta (here is the meta site for the entire SE network)

Comment: As for re-posting, that's almost-guaranteed to be a terrible idea: if your original post is now in shape, then the second is making a mess, and if not, then you're shooting yourself in the foot with a double-barrel, basically: the system tracks how well-received your posts are, and if you consistently post not-well-received posts, you can very well put yourself into an automatic question ban. Don't double-post, fix your existing posts instead!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I received feedback that I needed to update the question, but it was closed before I was able to update it (I was still trying some other things and wanted to wait until I could update with results of all my own troubleshooting). Now that I've updated, will it possibly be reopened or should I just create a new question?

Updating your question will bump it automatically to the home page and the active questions tab.

Thus it's likely to get more views again and maybe receiving reopen votes.

You should just be patient, instead of asking a new question.

Deleting a question and asking a new one is always prone for a possible question ban if done repeatedly.

Comment: And as Mathieu said above, the very first edit after closure puts the question into the reopen review queue too. (Which is why it's generally bad for others to make minor cosmetic edits to freshly closed questions, since it deprives the OP of the chance of fixing it before it gets reviewed).